# Is ffmpeg running in CPU or GPU?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, gpu

It has been shown in the link

> https://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/IntelPerformanceTuning/
>
> Step 2: CPU vs GPU

that if the CPU % is more than 90 then the app is running in CPU.

While configuring ffmpeg, I enabled opencl. ffmpeg configurations are,

```
ffmpeg version ebe0fa0 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-opencl --enable-nonfree --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libaacplus
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

But while running ffmpeg using the command

ffmpeg -i /home/M.mp4 -c:v h264 -preset:v faster /home/out.avi

the CPU% has been more than 90 (375%).

In case of ImageMagick, if I enable opencl while configuring, then the app will run in GPU, i.e., the CPU% will be less than 90. I noticed that.

But in case of ffmpeg, it is GPU accelerated one. Then, Why the CPU% is more than 90%? Is the ffmpeg running in CPU or GPU? If it is not, how can I make it to run in GPU?

Comment: ffmpeg running in `CPU`. Reference link [here](http://superuser.com/questions/917693/force-ffmpeg-to-use-100-of-cpu).

Comment: I believe only certain encoders / decoders / features are hardware-acceleration enabled. Refer to the tables here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro … In your case, for example, you could use `-c:v nvenc_h264` to use an NVidia card to encode H.264 video. OpenCL only seems to support filtering, if the source is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem.

Comment: I am using Intel QSV. So in the link  trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro it is yes. So in case of Quick Sync will it run in GPU??

Comment: Can you give more information about execution platform: CPU Model, Operation system, and more?

Answer (score 13):

To work on the gpu you should enable the video encoding/decoding technology in the settings, and after, for each command you should specify the correct parameter, basing on what hardware you have.

Sometimes, if you add this parameter, ffmpeg works on your gpu even without enabling anything in the config.

#### Encode AVI to h.264 Video (Software Encoding)

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 output.mp4`

#### Encode AVI to h.265 Video (Software Encoding)

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx265 output.mp4`

#### Encode AVI to h.264 Video (AMD GPU Encoding)

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v h264_amf output.mp4`

#### Encode AVI to h.265 Video (AMD GPU Encoding)

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v hevc_amf output.mp4`

#### Encode AVI to h.264 Video (NVIDIA GPU Encoding)

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4`

#### Encode AVI to h.265 Video (NVIDIA GPU Encoding)

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v hevc_nvenc output.mp4`